# How to trigger form validation on button click in angular2

Tags: javascript, validation, angular

I am working on angular2 application in which I have to apply validation on the input fields.

I have same code here

http://plnkr.co/edit/6RkM0eRftf3KQpoDCktz?p=preview

Its work fine for me but i want to trigger the validation on button click and show the all the validation messages which are invalid

currently it activated when i click on fields.

I have tried this

```
saveUser() {
        if (this.userForm.valid) {
            alert(`Name: ${this.userForm.value.name} Email: ${this.userForm.value.email}`);
        } else {
            this.userForm.validator();
        }
    }
```

Its not working as expected.

How do i trigger those validation on button click, I want button to be active all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to leverage a `submitted` property of the form control when displaying errors. This could be used in the corresponding `ngIf` to display these messages.

```
<span *ngIf="submitted && !this.userForm.controls.email.valid">...</span>
```

You need to initialize the `submitted` property to false by default and set it to true when calling the `saveUser` method:

```
@Component({
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.submitted = false;
  }

  saveUser() {
    this.submitted = true;
    (...)
  }
}
```

This way they will be visible only after the form has been submitted.

Comment: Can you please give me more details  how to do that

Comment: is it not possible to handle in  controlmessages.component in  "get errorMessage " so that it applicable in all places

Comment: Other wise i need to do it every where

Comment: Yes sure but you need to manage the submitted property by your own. That said you could set it directly on the form controller. If you have access in your controlmessages component, you wouldn't need to another parameter to it...